# log4j2 RollingFile Appender not changing filename on Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, log4j, log4j2

I have a web application using `log4j2`. The logs should be created on a daily basis.

Problem: the content of the old file never gets deleted, but any new day is just appended to that file. So it grows continuously. Is the following confniguration correct in general, when running on a `tomcat8`?

log4j2.xml:

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="TEST" fileName="d:\test-application.txt" filePattern="d:\test-application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        //...
        <RollingFile>
    //...
    </Appenders>
    //...
</Configuration>
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not the first person to report this behavior and the common factor seems to be Windows. Log4j tries to rename the file. If that fails it tries to copy and delete then delete the file.  If there is a lock on the file the rename will fail and then most likely the copy is succeeding but the delete is failing. But the code is still using the delete method of the File object, which is not good at reporting errors and Log4j isn't checking the return value, so it is failing silently.

This behavior is a bug and should be fixed, but it won't really solve your problem - it will just let you know about it. To fix it you need to find out what is preventing the rename from succeeding.

Answer (score 0):

What we often see is multiple processes or multiple web applications using the same log4j2.xml configuration and logging to the same file. One process will then prevent the other from deletion the file.

I've had this problem when I kept the log file open in an editor, and the midnight rollover would fail because of this.

Comment: It happens mostly when I'm using tomcats `parallel deployment`, thus installing an updated version from a war file with `myfile##3.war`, and then undeploying the previous version after the new is launched. Maybe the dynamically undeployed version then still locks the logfile? Both application write to the same...

Comment: Can you test by using a different config (different log file) when parallel deploying?